# Free shipping price rule is not applying to Fedex rate

Tags: shipping, price-rules, ce-1.9.2.1

I believe I'm encountering a bug with the Fedex shipping calculation (might be problem with other carriers).

## Steps to Replicate

- Enable Fedex rates
- Configure "Home Delivery" as the free method
- Create a price rule to apply free shipping to a single sku (e.g. `test-123`)
- Add sku `test-123` to your cart
- Add another item to your cart (sku `somethingelse-456`)

## Expected Result

- When shipping is calculated, sku `test-123` should not be taken into account.
- I.e. the shipping rate for a cart consisting of skus `test-123` and `somethingelse-456` should be the same as the shipping rate for a cart with sku `somethingelse-456`

## Actual Result

- The free shipping rule is not used and the Fedex rate includes the cost of shipping the `test-123` item.

---

I have tested this on a clean CE 1.9.2.1 install with sample data.

For an example of how it should work, consider flat rate shipping.  With a $5 flat rate per item, the cost to ship my 2 items would be $10, however because of the price rule, it is only $5.

Is this a bug?  Has anyone else experienced this?  What is the solution?

---

Here are some screen shots to further explain the issue:

[image: ss1]
[image: ss2]
[image: ss3]

Answer (score 2):

yes, It's a bug.

you need to override this file

Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Freeshipping

code your logic in collect function.

```
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    parent::collect($address);
    $quote = $address->getQuote();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId());

    $address->setFreeShipping(0);
    $items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);
    if (!count($items)) {
        return $this;
    }
    $this->_calculator->init($store->getWebsiteId(), $quote->getCustomerGroupId(), $quote->getCouponCode());

    $isAllFree = true;
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->getNoDiscount()) {
            $isAllFree = false;
            $item->setFreeShipping(false);
        } else {
            /**
             * Child item discount we calculate for parent
             */
            if ($item->getParentItemId()) {
                continue;
            }
            $this->_calculator->processFreeShipping($item);
            $isItemFree = (bool)$item->getFreeShipping();
            $isAllFree = $isAllFree && $isItemFree;
            if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isChildrenCalculated()) {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    $this->_calculator->processFreeShipping($child);
                    /**
                     * Parent free shipping we apply to all children
                     */
                    if ($isItemFree) {
                        $child->setFreeShipping($isItemFree);
                    }

                }
            }


            /*
             *  recalculate fedex price
             */

           // Your Logic here

            /*
             * 
             * end code
             */

        }
    }
    if ($isAllFree && !$address->getFreeShipping()) {
        $address->setFreeShipping(true);
    }
    return $this;
}
```